# How to define Resettability and persistence of an InstanceId in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Resettability and persistence**
Resettability and persistence define the lifespan of the identifier and explain how it can be reset. Common reset triggers are: in-app resets, resets via System Settings, resets on launch, and resets on installation. Android Identifiers can have varying lifespans, but the lifespan is usually related to how the ID is reset:

**Session-only** - a new ID is used every time the user restarts the app.

**Install-reset** - a new ID is used every time user uninstalls and reinstalls the app.

**FDR-reset** - a new ID is used every time the user factory-resets the device.

**FDR-persistent** - the ID survives factory reset.

how tho define these above resettability and persistence while implementing instance id in android App?

Thanks

Comment: still not found